# Set text in textbox in internet explorer in VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel

This is the HTML code of the textbox:

```html
<td>
  <input type="text" 
         name="maskString1" 
         size="32" 
         style="text-transform: uppercase" 
         onkeyup="determineType(this, document.accForm.searchType1)" 
         onblur= "mask('masksearchString1','searchString1','1', document.accLookForm.searchType1 )" 
         onfocus="unmask('maskString1','searchString1',document.accForm.searchType1,'1')"
  >
```

I have automated it in VBA Code:

```vba
ie.Document.All("masksearchString1").Value = "0000000044455458"
```

But the problem is this text box is a cascading textbox. After we enter value in the textbox the value of the next combobox changes accordingly.

But while running this code the value gets pasted in the textbox but the combobox value does not get changed.

Is there any way to place the cursor in the textbox and then paste the value so that the cascading functionality works?

Answer (score 1):

Try **'Focus()'** or **'FireEvent()'** methods. Short example here. HTH

```
' Add refernces to
' - Microsoft Internet Controls
' - Microsoft HTML Object Library

Option Explicit

Private Const URL As String = "C:/Temp/page1.html"

Sub test()
    Dim internet_browser As InternetExplorer
    Dim html_document As HTMLDocument

    Set internet_browser = New InternetExplorer

    With internet_browser
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        Do While .Busy And Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set html_document = .document

        Dim x As HTMLInputElement
        Set x = html_document.all("maskString1222")
        If Not x Is Nothing Then
            ' x.Focus ... gets focus
            x.Value = "0000000044455458"
            x.FireEvent "onkeyup" ' ... or fire some other event by its name
        End If

Quit:
        .Quit
    End With

    Set html_document = Nothing
    Set internet_browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey daniel,Thaks for your help.But i have a problem in this ..Your code is working only when the textbox is not focused....but here in my appplication after the page gets navigated the textbox is automatically focussed and the code x.value="0000000044455458" is not working....So i dont know how to proceed....

Comment: Ok, textbox is automatically focused but VBA code x.Value="..." should not be influenced by this at all. You have some java script functions defined for events like 'onfocus', 'onkeyup' etc. What are those functions do? Could the java script be the reason why the value is not set correctly? E.g. some validations occure? If possible try to outcomment calls to those functions and watch what happens.